# How to tokenize a line of text from a file

Tags: python

Suppose the file shakespeare.txt contained the single line. Famously spoken by Juliet in Romeo and 
Juliet: 
    "O Romeo, Romeo!  wherefore art thou Romeo?"

Then running the command `$ shakesort` should produce the following output

```
art
o
romeo
thou
wherefore
```

my code so far:

```
def main():
    s = Scanner("shakespeare.txt")
    tokens = ("O Romeo, Romeo! wherefore art thou Romeo?")
    str1 = s.readtoken()
    str2 = s.readtoken()
    str3 = s.readtoken()
    str4 = s.readtoken()
    str5 = s.readtoken()
    str6 = s.readtoken()
    str7 = s.readtoken()
    print(str1)
    print(str2)
    print(str3)
    print(str4)
    print(str5)
    print(str6)
    print(str7)
    s.close
    return 0;

main()
```

My problem is that it returns the first 7 strings of the entire file, rather than the token specified. How do I go about specified those 7 words from the full Shakespeare.txt(which contains millions of words) without making a new file and just listing those words?

Comment: What's readtoken() doing ?

Comment: There is a great tool called NLTK for this kind of problems: [http://www.nltk.org/](http://www.nltk.org/)

Comment: What is `Scanner`? Why did you expect anything other than the first seven words from calling `readtoken` seven times?

Comment: are you doing sort or just return 7 strings from the file?

Comment: s.readtoken is reading the word associated with that string
str1 = s.readtoken() is reading the first word of the file

Comment: @brainstorm
I will be doing a sort, I already have my shakesort code correct, this code above is printing the first 7 words in the txt file instead of the "O romeo o rome wherefore art thou romeo" Here I am trying to return the "O romeo o romeo...." which is found in the large text file mentioned above

Comment: How do you link your scanner with `Token` ? Can you show the code ?

Comment: can you use generator and extract the line out?

Comment: @jonrsharpe
Im taking my first coding course now so im not well versed in this at all, and that's what im wondering, our notes go over specifying tokens to strings, but that's what im trying to figure out. Is how to print the "O Romeo", where each word is its own token.

Comment: But you aren't *doing anything* with `tokens`! You define it, then ignore it.

Comment: I recognize this Scanner class from my time in CS150 at UA, which I assume you're taking as well based on the projects website.  The Scanner is for working with text files only.  Based on your description, it sounds like you want to use it on that string for test data.  If you want test data, you should just make a new file with those words and point the scanner to that.

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
    uniqwords = {}
    with open('shakespeare.txt') as f:
        for ln in f:
            words = ln.split()
            for word in words:
                word = word.replace('?', '').replace('!', '').replace(',', '').lower()
                uniqwords.setdefault(word, 0)

    for word in sorted(uniqwords.keys()):
        print word
```

Comment: awesome! is there a way to edit the bottom portion of the code to only print out the tokenize form of the line? that fully sorts and removes special characters, however we have to have our sort function from our shell file, how could I edit that for it to only remove the special characters and not sort it?

Comment: uniqwords is just a dictionary use it to extract & sort anyway you want